# Javascript: data format, akin to Spring Property Editors

Tags: javascript

Is there any library already available for javascript data format / transformation?

Example: Date, Time, Numbers, etc., can be converted to text with predefined formats.

These formats are chiefly locale based. But some how the mechanism to convert value (data, date, time..) should be there, that accepts custom format too to translate into desired formatted text.

On the contrary, the same library should be capable of parsing the text to value, with the source format knowledge.

Some thing similar to Spring's Property Editors or Converter.

Quick Searches; http://numeraljs.com/   http://www.datejs.com/

I should have mentioned the fact that, I am using DOJO as our JS Widget Library and with it comes methods and classes to address formatting / parsing, bundled.

Now that we have DOJO in place, I will be putting the code in the abstract layer (wrapper) over the library to keep the solution Library-Agnostic.

Find the code below - for brevity only the snippet is mentioned, could have done JSFiddle (may be in a day or two).

```
// get the DOJO handle, either from global "dojo" variable or via AMD
// var dojo = require('dojo'); 
  ............
// for date
  dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(), {selector: "date",datePattern:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
// output: 31/06/2013

// for number
 dojo.number.format(9999999.99,{type: "decimal",pattern:"#,##,####.##"});
// output: 9,99,9999.99

  ............
```

NOTE: An important feature it addresses is that it understands locale and can do the formatting automatically w.r.t the locale configured. DOJO library staunchly follows Java style of data formatting. If you are a Java Geek, you would find the library and format semantics easy to follow.

Find the DOJO link in this respect ://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/numbersDates.html  **(could not post the complete link as I do not have enough reputations, please prefix "http" to the link)**

Still, I would like to welcome better solution if any, for the given context.
As part of libraries used, we are using jQuery, Underscore, Backbone and DOJO primarily , all across for specific purposes in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I use Moment.js for all my JS date formatting and manipulations. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Yes limc, I found this handy for date & time surely (it has topped in the search results too). But I am looking for some kind of localization library addressing the requirement on all types of data.